# Multiple sites under single django code base using mod_wsgi

Tags: django

I am planning to have multiple site running from one Django Codebase using Apache + mod_wsgi.
Could anyone please help me in achieving this.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655548/how-to-host-50-domains-sites-with-common-django-code-base/3058693

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you need to change between the various sites?  How many sites are you dealing with?

Comment: currently I am planning to create three sites. two sites share a common database and one site has a different database. Consider there are three sites A,B,C in which site "A" and site "B" have same Database (i.e. DB1) and site "C" may have database DB2. The users from the user Table in database "DB1" (i.e. users for sites "A" and "B") need to be associated with a user in database "DB2" (i.e. users for sites "C"). Please advice how to achieve this. 

All the sites may share common items too.

Please advice how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

- every Django project should have it's own mod.wsgi file (not necessarily called mod.wsgi, btw) which looks like :

  ```
  import os, sys
  sys.path.append('DJANGO_PATH')
  sys.path.append('DJANGO_PATH/SITEPATH')
  os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'SITE.settings'

  import django.core.handlers.wsgi
  application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
  ```

  where DJANGO_PATH is the path where all your Django projects were created, SITEPATH is the folder where your specific project resides.
- in Apache make a virtualhost for every site that refers to their own mod.wgsi files, like :

  ```
  WSGIScriptAlias / /DJANGOPATH/SITEPATH/mod.wsgi
  ```

repeat for all sites.

Comment: ok agreed, but consider if I need a common authentication technique need to be applied for these two sites. how can I achieve this without replicating the code and resource. These two sites may be using its own database and the authentication User table is supposed to be a different database. Is there a way to achieve this. Please advice

Comment: You could use a LDAP database to authenticate against. In the settings.py file in each project you can set the databases for the application data. In that case their both not used for authentication/user data.

Answer (score 0):

Use different [settings modules](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/).

Comment: Hi,

Could you please elaborate. I need to dynamically import the site specific settings files into the global setting file. Could you please help me how can I achieve this with Apache + mod_wsgi

Comment: Import the global settings in the site-specific settings.